# Php object is not visible to html subtemplate?

Tags: php, html, oop

Im a complete noob to PHP but have a decent working knowledge of OO. I'm working on a project the displays a persons profile.
I have a **profile.php** which takes a patient's id number and creates a person object and then renders an html template below. The html template is supposed to display the patient's vitals and other information. I have three inserts, two of which work.

the problem i am having is that  in my `profile.php` I create a `$person` object and I have verified this works by outputting the $person's full name and id. However when render the html template `profile.html` .... $person does not seem to be visible there specifically it is the `/inserts/_patient_form.php` which does not seem to be able to access my `$person` object. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Still trying to understand the various quirks of php.... should I be declaring something global?

**profile.php**

```
<?php 

include_once('../mysql_connect.php');
include_once('includes/classes/person.php');
include_once('includes/classes/stats.php');
include_once('includes/classes/note.php');
include_once('includes/classes/prescription.php');
include_once('includes/functions.php');


  //Define the query
if (isset($_GET['patient']) && is_numeric($_GET['patient']) && ($_GET['patient'] > 0)){




$person = Person::find_by_id($_GET['patient']);

$name = $person->getFullName();
$id = $person->getId();

define('TITLE', $name . '\'s Profile');
include('templates/header.html');
include('templates/profile.html');
include('templates/footer.html');


} else { // Couldn't get the information
define('TITLE', 'Invalid Profile');
include('templates/header.html');
print '<p class="error">This is an invalid page, or this patient doesn\'t exist..</p>';
include('templates/footer.html');
}

mysql_close($dbc);// Close the connection
?>
```

**profile.html**

```
<h2 style="margin-bottom:10px;"><?php print $name ?></h2>
  <p id="message"></p>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="patient-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#statistics" data-toggle="tab">Statistics</a></li>
   <li><a href="#notes-prescriptions" data-toggle="tab">Notes and Prescriptions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="statistics">
    <?php include('inserts/_patient_entries.php'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="notes-prescriptions">
  <?php include('inserts/_patient_notes.php'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    <?php include('inserts/_person_form.php'); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

**/inserts/_patient_form.php**

```
print '
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="ajax/person_update.php" id="patient-form">
  <input name="id" type="hidden" value="' . $person->getId() . '" required="">

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" value="' . $person->first_name . '" class="input-xlarge" required="">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" value="' . $person->last_name . '" class="input-xlarge" required="">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . $person->email . '" class="input-xlarge" required="">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" value="' . $person->phone . '" class="input-xlarge">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Age</label>
    <div class="controls">
   <input id="age" name="age" type="text" value="' . $person->age . '" class="input-xlarge" required="">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Address</label>
    <div class="controls">                     
      <textarea id="address" name="address" rows="5" cols="300" style="width:270px;">' . $person->address . '</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Insurance</label>
<div class="controls">                     
  <textarea id="insurance" name="insurance" rows="5" cols="300" style="width:270px;">' . $person->insurance . '</textarea>
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">New Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" class="input-xlarge">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="singlebutton" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  </form>
';
?>
```

Comment: The code above should work

Comment: No it won't until he changes his HTML files containing PHP code to files with the .php extension. Remembering of course he already has a profile.php file he's going to have to pick a different name for profile.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a given file contains PHP code, it must have a PHP extension. In most cases this is .php, but you can also configure the .htaccess file to read the PHP code in the HTML file without renaming it or changing its extension. In most cases the .htaccess file will just need this:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .html .htm
```